# High amount of requests for AWS S3 for a small mobile app

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-billing

I am doing a mobile app with React Native using AWS Services, which is basically a CRUD app for images, and I am relatively new to it.

My fees seems very high for AWS S3 (look at the picture below). I know the amount is still very small but I am concerned on how did my app requested more than 91k times on barely 2 months. I tried to debug my app, but it's impossible that I requested the AWS server that many times. I looked for any loops in my project and there is nothing, I even looked at the network and didn't found anything suspicious.

[image]

I tried to analyze what could it be with cloud watch as well but I don't see any metrics that would represent these S3 requests.

To display images on my React Native app, I am using the [react-native-fast-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image?activeTab=versions) module.

Is there a way to debug/find what is causing these calls? Has anyone experienced a similar thing with AWS S3? Are DynamoDB query calls based on S3 as well?

Comment: Yes, DynamoDB uses S3 for storage.  Ideally, you can instrument your app - that's definitely the best place to start.  But S3 has extensive logging capabilities, too.  Look here: [Logging requests using server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html) and here: [Using Amazon S3 access logs to identify requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-s3-access-logs-to-identify-requests.html).

Comment: Thanks I am looking at that! What do you mean by instrument my app? Not familiar with these logging requests for the moment, would they identify if those requests are made by DynamoDB or by actual S3 calls for images? Any thoughts?

Comment: you could use CloudTrail Event history (no cost) or you could enable CloudTrail with management and data Events. Please note data events will consume more usage and API calls
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudtrail-data-management-events/

Comment: @FoggyDay FYI, DynamoDB has its own storage system to provide fast, predictable performance. It does not use Amazon S3 for storage.

Comment: You can setup S3 access logs.

Comment: @Citrix: read the links Sri and I gave you.  AWS gives you PLENTY of logging options to determine how your S3 storage is getting used